# What is BROKER_USER and BROKER_PASSWORD?

Tags: python, django, celery

What is `BROKER_USER` and `BROKER_PASSWORD` in django celery?
This is user name and password from super user in Django? If not, how to set user and password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is BROKER_USER and BROKER_PASSWORD in django celery?

These are the credentials for the underlying queue framework (generally AMQP).

You can choose between:

- [RabbitMQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#rabbitmq)
- [Redis](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#redis)
- [Using a database](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#using-a-database)
- [Some other brokers](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#other-brokers)

Comment: For RabbitMQ see http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html#broker-rabbitmq

Comment: @user1966421 First you need to set up an AMQP or other server from above, and then use the user and password for that service. This configuration happens outside of Django.

Answer (score 0):

It's your brokers username and password, this could be AMQP for instance.

Here's an example: [Configuring your Django project to use Celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html#configuring-your-django-project-to-use-celery)

Comment: Link rotted away :-(